# how do you write a loop in a shell script for imagemagick and multiple mogrify commands

Tags: shell, loops, imagemagick

I'm using windows 7, cygwin, and imagemagick v6.7.6 with the following mogrify command...

---

```
mogrify \
-verbose \
-draw 'image over 0,0 0,0 "/cygdrive/L/temp/logo.png"' \
-gravity southeast \
-path /cygdrive/L/temp/og-rotate-logo *.jpg \
-adaptive-resize 1200x1200 \
-path /cygdrive/L/temp/1200px *.jpg
```

---

This currently does work, however not the way I wish it did.  I think that I need some kind of loop to do what I need, but have no idea what to do.

Basically right now the above command adds a logo to the source photo and saves it to a folder called og-rotate-logo, then after all the source images are done in the source folder it moves onto the next step and resizes all the new logo photos down to 1200x1200 and saves that photo in a folder called 1200px.  This is the result I need, however I would like to do all the commands on each photo one step at a time. Such as taking the source image, adding the logo, saving in og-rotate-logo folder, then resizing down to 1200x1200, saving in the 1200px folder and then moving on to the next image in the source folder.

First is there a way for me to re-write my mogrify command to do this in the steps I want or is this also possible by writing some kind of shell script file to loop or something. I have absolutely no idea how to do this, would love to learn and if anyone has the time to help that would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: Out of interest why are you using Cygwin when there seems to be no reason to do that? Also why the -verbose?

Comment: i don't know why i'm using cygwin other then it works for me.  what should i be using?  and i like verbose so that i can see it working, i take it out at the end to save some on speed because i'm working with thousands of photos at once.

Comment: There is nothing in your code posted that needs a Linux environment and should run from the windows command line as long as you change the / in the paths to \ ( I think ). Thinking about it why are you running such an old version as well? I have V7 installed on my Windows 10 computer.

Comment: honestly @bonzo i don't have the skills needed to upgrade my version of IM.  and as a side question is there any benefit to running in windows command line vs cygwin?  i'm such a newbie and have got myself this far with just research online and obviously been lucky.  i tried to upgrade IM with cygwin but pretty sure i failed with the procedure, but don't really know because the old version is probably still working

Comment: I use IM in windows and can't see the point in using Cygwin; it is another layer of code. You can run IM from the command line or from a batch file. I have a batch file I just drop photos over the icon to resize them. Linux is a bit of a pain ( ready for castigation here ) as they start off with a version of IM and instead of updating it they keep patching it. BUT they sometimes miss things out so your install will not be fully up to date. You can install IM on windows from an exe file - make sure you allow the install to add to environmental path. Version 7 uses magick and not convert.

Comment: @Bonzo can you help make this cygwin code work on windows cmd?
 I think I've got imagemagick working on my laptop with windows install....'code that works on cygwin' for f in *.jpg; do
convert "$f" \
-verbose \
-gravity southeast \
-draw 'image over 0,0 0,0 "/cygdrive/L/temp/logo.png"' \
-write /cygdrive/L/temp/og-rotate-logo/"$f" \
-resize 1200x1200 \
/cygdrive/L/temp/1200px/"$f"
done

Answer (score 1):

I do not use mogrify and this is adapted from some convert code I use that may work:

```
mogrify \
( -clone 0 -draw 'image over 0,0 0,0 "/cygdrive/L/temp/logo.png"' -gravity southeast -write -path /cygdrive/L/temp/og-rotate-logo *.jpg +delete ) \
-adaptive-resize 1200x1200 -path /cygdrive/L/temp/1200px *.jpg
```

Ah this will not work as it is saving the original image in the second write not the one with the logo.

What does this do:

```
mogrify -draw 'image over 0,0 0,0 "/cygdrive/L/temp/logo.png"' -gravity southeast -adaptive-resize 1200x1200 -path /cygdrive/L/temp/1200px *.jpg
```

Third go! You probably need the first -write:

```
mogrify -draw 'image over 0,0 0,0 "/cygdrive/L/temp/logo.png"' -gravity southeast -write -path /cygdrive/L/temp/og-rotate-logo *.jpg -adaptive-resize 1200x1200 -path /cygdrive/L/temp/1200px *.jpg
```

After the comment about wanting a Windows version. The below works but for some reason I get an error and on thousands of files it could be a pain!

Save as a batch file, create the new folders and run using the example - use some test files first.

```
::Turn of displaying the code on the screen
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Example command to run in the command box
REM Path to the batch file - originals file - logo added folder - resized folder
REM C:\Users\bonzo\Desktop\test.bat G:\Upload\originals G:\Upload\test G:\Upload\test1  

for %%f in (%1\*.jpg) do ( convert "%%f" -gravity southeast -draw "image over 0,0 0,0 ""G:\Upload\logo.png"" " -write "%2\%%~nf.jpg" -resize 200x200 -write "%3\%%~nf.jpg" )
```

EDIT:
I have removed the error problem and changed the -draw to composite:

```
for %%f in (%1\*.jpg) do ( convert  "%%f" -gravity southeast "G:\Upload\logo.png" -composite -write "%2\%%~nf.jpg" -resize 200x200 -write "%3\%%~nf.jpg" null: )
```

Comment: well thanks for the reply, but it tried it and got an error saying -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `-clone'

Comment: Change ( ) to \\( \\) but I am not sure the first example does what you want and that is why I included the second example

Comment: what does this do?  answer: that adds the logo, reduces the size, then saves it in the 1200px folder.  so it's missing the first step where it takes the source image adds the logo then saves it to og-rotate-logo folder.

Comment: i think the research i've done shows i should be writing some kind of file to execute that has variables.  something like this 'code'  for f in *.jpg; do
  convert ./"$f" ./"${f%.jpg}.pdf"
done

Comment: Your above comment code would not run in a Linux environment as it is for Windows.

Comment: sorry to confuse things @Bonzo I'm a newbie woobee

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the order for some reason, you are going to be better off with your own loop and `convert`. I don't *do* Windows, but the command for one file will be:

```
convert InputFile.jpg \
  -gravity southeast  \
  -draw 'image over 0,0 0,0 "/cygdrive/L/temp/logo.png"' \
  -write /some/where/file.jpg                            \
  -resize 1200x1200                                      \
  /some/where/else/finalResult.jpg
```

So, you will need to put a loop around that which will look something like this abomination:

```
FOR /F ["options"] %%L IN (*.jpg) DO (
    convert %%L                                              \
      -gravity southeast                                     \
      -draw 'image over 0,0 0,0 "/cygdrive/L/temp/logo.png"' \
      -write /some/where/%%L                                 \
      -resize 1200x1200                                      \
      /some/where/else/%%L
}
```

Or, if Windows can do something more like `bash`

```
for f in *.jpg; do
    convert "$f"                                             \
      -gravity southeast                                     \
      -draw 'image over 0,0 0,0 "/cygdrive/L/temp/logo.png"' \
      -write /some/where/"$f"                                \
      -resize 1200x1200                                      \
      /some/where/else/"$f"
done
```

Comment: thanks mark.. that is the approach i was thinking i need to do..   so i copied your 'bash' example made the changes to the folders as needed and boom it works!  but i didn't realize that i couldn't stop it!  lol then moved all the source photos so it eventually stopped hah as there were thousands of photos in my test folder oops..  anyway is there a way to break the 'covert' and stop it that i should be aware of.  thanks for the help!

Comment: I really don't know much at all about Windows. I would try `Ctrl-C`.

Comment: yes! your code is working great and the ctrl-c does break the for loop